# how to implement multi tenancy in kafka consumer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

I will pass the tenant id to the Kafka producer and in the consumer, I need to decide the database based on the tenant id.
will it be possible using c#

Comment: tenant id can be passed as part of message in kafka. Is there some other issue that I am missing here?

Comment: ok but the DB configuration for the rest of the activities needs to be decided based on the tenant id..How the web API will decide the database ?as the consumer is in the web api

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve] so that we can understand better